# Best OOP approach and practice

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm attempting to follow best OOP practices for this task. My goal is to use the 'creature' class across enemy and player class. This way they can inherit certain re-useable code such as attack, defend, death, and stats(hp, attack etc...). I thought I was on the right path, but now I'm really stuck because I can't find ways to implement this correctly, and most importantly I'm not sure if I'm following best practices.

I want my structure to look like this:

```
   Creature
      |
      |
     / \
 enemy player
         \
       classes
```

Here's some code to illustrate a bit better if needed.

```
public class creature {
    
    protected static int hp = 150;
    protected static int mp = 35;
    protected static int str = 10;
    protected static int dex = 10;
    protected static int intell = 10;
    protected static int mnd = 10;
    protected static int lck = 10;
    protected static int attack = 15;
    protected static int level = 1;
    protected static int enemyHP = 150;
    
//  public static int playerAttack(int attackDmg) {
//      int damageDealt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(7, attackDmg);
//      return damageDealt;
//  }
    
    public static int defend(int dmgReduction) {
        int damageTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(25, dmgReduction);
        return damageTaken;
    }
    
    public static void enemyDeath(int enemyHP) {
        
    }
    
    public static void playerDeath() {
        
    }
}
```

And an enemy class;

```
public class enemy extends creature {   
    //potentially store values in an array to randomly select value, then add hp of each enemy
    //such that 155 selected, Brittle Skeleton HP modifier could be + 5 hp, or * 1.86 etc...
    static int[] enemy_HP = {155, 144, 129};
    public static String brittleSkeleton() {
        
        String enemy = "Brittle Skeleton";
        creature.hp += 5;
        creature.mp += 15;
        creature.str += 1;
        creature.dex += 2;
        creature.intell += 4;
        creature.mnd += 0;
        creature.lck += 3;      
        return enemy;
    }
    
    public static int getBrittleSkeletonHp() {
    //  int damageDone = enemy.hp - mage.getAttack();
        return enemy.hp;
    }
    
    public int enemyAttack() {
        return enemy.attack;
    }
    public static int getEnemyRemainingHealth() {
        
        return enemy.enemyHP - mage.getAttack();
    }
}
```

Any advice is welcome, I'm still new to this, but I want to make sure I have great structured code that makes sense. How should I structure this? And what I have currently, does it make sense to structure it this way?

Comment: I think you misunderstand `static` -- there's one instance for all objects of that class and all of its subclasses.  So changing those values in `enemy` (please use Java standard class names - `Enemy`) changes them for all creatures, enemies and players.  Also, `Creature` having `enemyDeath()` and `playerDeath()` is just wrong.

Comment: There is no such thing as "best practices", everyone has their own opinion what is "best", and even for a single person "best" might be pretty fluid depending on the project and context.

Comment: Thank you @ Jim. Appreciate the feedback! And thank you @ Mark, that actually clears up a lot. Maybe I'm trying too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `creature` more general..e.g `death` instead of `enemyDeath`...then override death (and others similar in both) in the subclass with a call to `super` as in....

```java
public class creature {
    ...
//also exclude static keywords 
//  public int playerAttack(int attackDmg) {
//      int damageDealt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(7, attackDmg);
//      return damageDealt;
//  }
    // all common options here
    public int defend(int dmgReduction) {
        int damageTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(25, dmgReduction);
        return damageTaken;
    }
     // this is removed
   // public void enemyDeath(int enemyHP) {}
    public static void death() {}
}
```

Now in subclass `enemy`...

```java
public class enemy extends creature {   
    ....// instance fields only found with enemy...
   // override death
   @Override
    public  void death() {
    // first makes sure defaults are set...eg what all deaths must have
    super.death();
    // now code unique to enemy
    }
}
```

The concept is just to generalize everything in creature ...
Then override methods for specific actions...